# How to create a “sessionId” column using timestamps and userid in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, session, pyspark

I have a data set which contains fields such as: userId, event, pageName, and timestamp, while lacking of the sessionId. I want to create a sessionId for each record based on the timestamp and a pre-defined value "finish" (which indicates after how many minutes of inactivity a session ends). Only users with the same UserId can be in the same session.

If the "finish" value is 30 minutes (1800 difference in timestamp), and a sample DataFrame is:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("blue", "view", 1610494094750, 11),
  ("green", "add to bag", 1510593114350, 21),
  ("red", "close", 1610493115350, 41),
  ("blue", "view", 1610494094350, 11),
  ("blue", "close", 1510593114312, 21),
  ("red", "view", 1610493114350, 41),
  ("red", "view", 1610593114350, 41),
  ("green", "purchase", 1610494094350, 31)
], ["item", "event", "timestamp", "userId"])


+-----+----------+-------------+------+
| item|     event|    timestamp|userId|
+-----+----------+-------------+------+
| blue|      view|1610494094750|    11|
|green|add to bag|1510593114350|    21|
|  red|     close|1610493115350|    41|
| blue|      view|1610494094350|    11|
| blue|     close|1510593114312|    21|
|  red|      view|1610493114350|    41|
|  red|      view|1610593114350|    41|
|green|  purchase|1610494094350|    31|
+-----+----------+-------------+------+
```

The end result should be something like this:

```
+--------+----------+-------------+------+---------+
|    item|     event|    timestamp|userId|sessionId|
+--------+----------+-------------+------+---------+
|    blue|     close|1510593114312|    21| session1|
|   green|add to bag|1510593114350|    21| session1|
|     red|      view|1610493114350|    41| session2|
|    blue|      view|1610494094350|    11| session3|
|     red|     close|1610493115350|    41| session2|
|   green|  purchase|1610494094350|    31| session4|
|    blue|      view|1610494094750|    11| session3|
|     red|      view|1610593114350|    41| session5|
+--------+----------+-------------+------+---------+
```

I'm trying to solve this problem using PySpark. Any advice is welcome.

Edit: I've edited the timestamp

Comment: what is the unit of timestamp ? how much does 30 minutes represents in "timestamp" difference?

Comment: @Steven 30 minutes in the timestamp is 1800. It's the timestamp that can be found here https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: please fix your data then. You example is completely wrong. difference in session3 for example is '180000'

Comment: @Steven My bad, sorry! I will fix it

Comment: @Steven It should be fixed now. I've divided the example into sessions manually so that's why there were errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the work:

```py
# Get the previous timestamp for each userid
df = df.withColumn(
    "session_id",
    F.lag("timestamp").over(Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")),
)

# Define if the session is the 1st one (more than 1800s after the previous one)
df = df.withColumn(
    "session_id",
    F.when(F.col("timestamp") - F.col("session_id") <= 1800, 0).otherwise(1),
)

# create a unic id per session (same id can exists for different users)
df = df.withColumn(
    "session_id",
    F.sum("session_id").over(Window.partitionBy("userid").orderBy("timestamp")),
)

# create a unic id per session per user
df = df.withColumn(
    "session_id", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("userid", "session_id"))
)
```

```
df.show()
+-----+----------+-------------+------+----------+                              
| item|     event|    timestamp|userId|session_id|
+-----+----------+-------------+------+----------+
| blue|      view|1610494094350|    11|         1|
| blue|      view|1610494094750|    11|         1|
| blue|     close|1510593114312|    21|         2|
|green|add to bag|1510593114350|    21|         2|
|green|  purchase|1610494094350|    31|         3|
|  red|      view|1610493114350|    41|         4|
|  red|     close|1610493115350|    41|         4|
|  red|      view|1610593114350|    41|         5|
+-----+----------+-------------+------+----------+
```